# how to store variables in django cache db

Tags: python, django

i am making a cache db using the django cache module
i configured it in my settings.py like this

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'my_cache_table',
    }
}
```

so in my something.py file
example

```
def function():
   log=cache['default']
   log["cal"]+=1
```

can i do this so that a variable like cal would be formed and it would increase every time i call that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure the cache table exists in your database.  Django provides a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#creating-the-cache-table) for this:

```
python3 manage.py createcachetable
```

Now to increment **`cal`**:

```
# a convenience import for the default cache
from django.core.cache import cache

def increment_cal():
    cal = cache.get_or_set('cal', 0)
    cal += 1
    cache.set('cal', cal)
```

There is only one problem, this code has a *race condition*. If multiple threads try to increment **`cal`** at the same time, you can get inaccurate results.

To fix this, you will need a thread lock:

```
import threading
from django.core.cache import cache

cal_lock = threading.Lock()

def increment_cal():
    with cal_lock:
        cal = cache.get_or_set('cal', 0)
        cal += 1
        cache.set('cal', cal)
```

Note that this only solves race conditions *between threads*.  If you have multiple processes trying to increment **`cal`**, you will need to use a [multiprocessing lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) instead.

Comment: hmm but in your code how will i get cal from my db which is currently default now

Comment: @YashBontala just call `cache.get('cal')`